# Don't Redirect to admin page after login in asp.net forms authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, web-config

In my asp.net web application, I'm using asp.net forms authentication with following configuration.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms defaultUrl="~/ManagePage/Default.aspx" loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="2880"></forms>
</authentication>

<roleManager enabled ="true" defaultProvider ="MyRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="MyRoleProvider" type="MyRoleProvider" connectionStringName="dbTaxiRaniConnectionString" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

And this is login button code :

```
if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        if (Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Alert.Show("Your Loged in ");
        }
        else
        {
            if (CheckLogin(UserName.Text.Trim(), Password.Text.Trim()) == true)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserName.Text.Trim(), RememberMe.Checked);

                if (Roles.GetRolesForUser(UserName.Text.Trim())[0] == "Admin")
                {
                    Session["CounterLogin"] = 0;
                    Response.Redirect("../ManagePage/Default.aspx");

                }
                else if (Roles.GetRolesForUser(UserName.Text)[0] == "Suport")
                {
                    Session["CounterLogin"] = 0;
                    Response.Redirect("../ManagePage/Default.aspx");

                }
            }
            else
            {
                int i = (int)Session["CounterLogin"];
                Session["CounterLogin"] = i + 1;

                i = (int)Session["CounterLogin"];

                if (i > 3)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

And this is web.config code include in admin folder  :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny roles="member"/>
      <allow roles="Admin,Suport" />
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

after click on login button user login work true but don't redirect to `~/ManagePage/Default.aspx` and show again login page.how can solve this problem ?

Comment: Are you sure the user has one of the two roles which let him get to `~/ManagePage/Default.aspx` page? If not, it is ok to redirect again to login page. And also, be careful with your statements like `if (Roles.GetRolesForUser(UserName.Text.Trim())[0] == "Admin")`, I may suggest you to change it to `Roles.IsUserInRole(username, rolename)`

Comment: zed : yes,i'm sure.this user role is Admin.

Comment: Anyway your code is buggy, what happens if your user has more roles than those two; and neither `Admin` nor `Support` are at index 0 position (because at that position the user has another role)? In that scenario the user won't pass login page. Try to change it as I suggest, it will be an improvement and also maybe the solution to your issue ;)

Comment: when try to login,login page reload and clear entered data in textbox and in addres bar on browser show this path : "http://localhost:2919/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FManagePage%2FDefault.aspx"

Comment: Try to debug your code to see line by line what is happening. See that it tried to reach `~/ManagePage/Default.aspx` but redirected again to login (hence you see the parameter `ReturnUrl`) so maybe the user does not have the permission to get there, or maybe your ManagePage/Default.aspx is doing some other checks and kicks to login page.

Comment: i try your suggestion to trace code and when run this code :Response.Redirect("../ManagePage/Default.aspx") thats redirect again to login